# actionscript break if statement to check next one

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I'm making a bot for a simple tic tac toe game. Here is the problem, at botCheck function, when row 0 col 0 and row 0 col 1 is "O", then the "X" appear at the row 0 col 2, and when I tried to make another combination of "O" (ex. row 0 col 0 and row 1 col 1), it should check at different if statement, but my code seems to still check only at the first if statement which will keep tracing ("D") and stuck at that part.

So here is the question, at `else{trace("D");}` , is there any code that I can replace  with to skip the first if statement and go to the second one so it can check for the other combinations of "O" ?

P.S. I've tried to use `continue;` but it only goes to the next loop and still stuck at the first if statement.

Thanks!

```
package
{
    public class Bot
    {
        private var n:int = 0;
        private var rndm:int;
        private var v:int;//vertical
        private var h:int;//horizontal
        private var moving:Boolean = false;;

        private var _main:Main;

        public function Bot(main:Main):void
        {
            _main = main;
        }

        private function randomNumber(min:Number, max:Number):Number
        {
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+max-min)+min);
        }

        public function botMove():void
        {
            botCheck();
            if(n == 0 && moving == false)
            {
                rndm = randomNumber(0,2);
                v = rndm;
                rndm = randomNumber(0,2);
                h = rndm;
                if(_main.squareArray[v][h] == 0)
                {
                    _main.squareArray[v][h] = 1;
                    _main.xoArray[v][h].push(_main.xo);
                    moving = true;
                    fillX();
                    n = 0;
                    _main.xo = "O";
                }

                else
                {
                    botMove();
                }
            }

            if(n == 1 && moving == false)
            {
                if(_main.squareArray[v][h] == 0)
                {
                    _main.squareArray[v][h] = 1;
                    _main.xoArray[v][h].push(_main.xo);
                    moving = true;
                    fillX();
                    n = 0;
                    _main.xo = "O";
                }
            }
        }
        private function fillX():void
        {

                _main.x_ = new X  ;
                _main.xoContainer.addChild(_main.x_);

                _main.x_.x = _main.gameWidth / _main.lebar *(1+(h))+ _main.gameWidth/(_main.lebar*4);
                _main.x_.y = _main.gameHeight / _main.panjang * (1+(v))+_main.gameHeight/(_main.panjang*4);
                _main.x_.width = _main.square.width / 2;
                _main.x_.height = _main.square.height / 2;
        }

        private function botCheck():void
        {

                for(var a:int = 0; a<_main.panjang;a++)
                {
                    if(n != 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    for(var b:int = 0;b<_main.lebar;b++)
                    {
                        if(_main.xoArray[a][b]=="O" && _main.xoArray[a][b+1] == "O")
                        {
                            if(b+2 < _main.lebar && _main.xoArray[a][b+2] == 0)
                            {
                                n = 1;
                                v = a;
                                h = b+2;
                                moving = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(_main.xoArray[a][b-1] == 0)
                            {
                                n = 1;
                                v = a;
                                h = b-1;
                                moving = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                trace("D");

                            }
                        }
                        else if(_main.xoArray[a][b] == "O" && _main.xoArray[a+1][b] =="O")
                        {
                            if(a+2 < _main.panjang && _main.xoArray[a+2][b] == 0)
                            {
                                n = 1;
                                v = a+2;
                                h = b;
                                moving = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(a != 0)
                            {
                                if(_main.xoArray[a-1][b] == 0)
                                {
                                    n = 1;
                                    v = a-1;
                                    h = b;
                                    moving = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }

                        else if(_main.xoArray[a][b]=="O" && _main.xoArray[a+1][b+1] == "O")
                        {trace("B");
                            if(a+2 < _main.panjang && b+2 < _main.lebar && _main.xoArray[a+2][b+2] == 0)
                            {
                                n = 1;
                                v = a+2;
                                h = b+2;
                                moving = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(a != 0)
                            {
                                if(_main.xoArray[a-1][b-1] == 0)
                                {
                                    n = 1;
                                    v = a-1;
                                    h = b-1;
                                    moving = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }

                        else if(_main.xoArray[a][b+2]=="O" && _main.xoArray[a+1][b+1] == "O")
                        {trace("A");
                            if(a+2 < _main.lebar && _main.xoArray[a+2][b] == 0)
                            {
                                n = 1;
                                v = a+2;
                                h = b;
                                moving = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        else if(_main.xoArray[a][b] == "O" && _main.xoArray[a+1][b-1] == "O")
                        {
                            if(a != 0 && b+1 < _main.lebar && _main.xoArray[a-1][b+1] == 0)
                            {
                                n = 1;
                                v = a-1;
                                h = b+1;
                                moving = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            n  = 0;
                            moving = false;
                        }
                    }
                }


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to check through all the if statements within the for loop, simply remove the "else"s from the other if statements.

Thus, your first if statement is fine, but the next if statement would go from

```
else if(_main.xoArray[a][b] == "O" && _main.xoArray[a+1][b] =="O")
```

to simply

```
if(_main.xoArray[a][b] == "O" && _main.xoArray[a+1][b] =="O")
```

(just omitting the else).

Repeat that for all of the other **outermost** "else if"'s in your loop.

Now, I see at the bottom you have a final "else" that sets n to 0 and moving to false.  If you make the changes listed above, you may remove that else block, and instead put those statements in the else block (n = 0; moving = false) at the very beginning of the for loop.  Therefore, unless any of the if statements are triggered, n will equal 0 and moving will equal false, which is the intended result.

You can also get rid of all of the empty else {} blocks within the for loop; they don't contribute anything anyway.  Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've thought of using if but I was confused where to put the else block(n=0; moving = false;) , the empty else block just for checking things at beginning though.